# Blazor. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100] An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, ant-design-blazor

I hope you can help me with this error that I get when selecting an element from a select. The first time I select the item it works without problems but once I try to change the item it shows the following error:

> crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Tablas.Objects.RSObject
> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Tablas.Objects.RSObject
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Tablas.Objects.RSObject,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AntDesign.Select.Internal.SelectOptionItem`2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Tablas.Objects.RSObject,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], AntDesign, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].TryInsert(RSObject key, SelectOptionItem`2 value, InsertionBehavior behavior) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[Tablas.Objects.RSObject,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[AntDesign.Select.Internal.SelectOptionItem`2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Tablas.Objects.RSObject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], AntDesign, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].Add(RSObject key, SelectOptionItem`2 value)
> at AntDesign.Select`2[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Tablas.Objects.RSObject,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].CreateDeleteSelectOptions() at AntDesign.Select`2.d__294[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[Tablas.Objects.RSObject,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task task)

I am using blazor with the AntDesign library. This is my component:

```
<FormItem Label="Object Container">
    <Select DataSource="@DDL_Objects"
       @bind-Value="@_defaultContainer.ObjectID"
       LabelName="@nameof(RSObject.ObjectCode)"
       ValueName="@nameof(RSObject.ObjectID).ToString()"
       DefaultActiveFirstItem="false"
       EnableSearch="true"
       Disabled="false">
    </Select>
</FormItem>
```

And this is my codebehind:

```
List<RSObject> DDL_Objects = null;
List<RSObject> DDL_ContaineeTypes = null;

var resultObjects = await API.GetAllObjectsToFillDropdown();
if (resultObjects.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   if (resultObjects.Content != null)
   {
      DDL_Objects = resultObjects.Content;
      DDL_ContaineeTypes = resultObjects.Content;
   }
}

_defaultContainer = DDL_Objects.Find(x => x.ObjectCode.Equals("CONTAINER"));
```